# Events in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I just migrated a database [MS Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) 2003 to MS Access 2007. But I have some problems with the events. 
When I opened the database (MS Access 2003) start form, I usually can click on the form and if I do double click on it, it will lead me to another form.

Now after migrating to MS Access 2007, when I opened my database start form (MS Access 2007) and double clicked on it, I got this box : "Enter Parameter Value".
And if I just click ok, I'll get an error: "The expression On Dbl Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: ODBC- call failed"

I tried to make an event in the "On Dbl Click" Property to open the another form, but it seems it doesn't work. Do you have any idea where should I look why I'm getting this error?

The screenshots for the error message that I'm getting:

http://picasaweb.google.com/tintincutes/UnbenanntesAlbum#5415010078716383954
http://picasaweb.google.com/tintincutes/UnbenanntesAlbum#5415009629637226818

Additional question:

I'm also getting an error, `ODBC - call failed`, if I enter a parameter.
Did I make any mistakes here?

---

Additional:

I checked the form where I'm having a problem and under "Data" I found under "Order by" the name "Revision.HUhrID". I deleted it and it worked. But when I checked the database access in Access 2003 it contained this "Revision.HUhrID". 
Do you think deleting this is a good idea? 
Here is the screenshot I made:
http://picasaweb.google.com/tintincutes/UnbenanntesAlbum#5415067821432425986

Comment: Why are you bothering to upgrade?

Comment: that's the order from the bosses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query requires somekind of time (Uhr) parameter then leaving it blank is probably resulting in the failed ODBC call.

You need to find what is supposed to be populating the parameter `HUHrId` for the query and fix it so that it passes it through.

Post the code that you are using on the OnDblClick event to open the form. If the form opens with an error then this probably a problem with the forms Record Source maybe caused by this missing parameter.

Parameters are often bound to form fields. So the record source in Form 2 may have a parameter bound to a value in Form 1.

Comment: @pjp: there is actually no code on the "OnDblClick" created. So I'm not so sure if this is causing the problem.

Comment: Look in the DoubleClick event in the form's property sheet. Perhaps something has been accidentally typed in there.

Comment: Ok then it must be related to the RecordSource of the form that you are opening.

Comment: @pjp & David W. Fenton: I found something, under "data" in this form I found that there is written in "Order By" which is: Revision.HUhrID. I deleted it and then the form works. strange